# UIButton in SubView of ScrollView not working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

My problem is that my Button is not working when im paging to my subView. Is the button located on the ScrollView everything works fine.

**Main ViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.sView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
self.sView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.sView.frame.size.width,
                                    self.sView.frame.size.height*2);
self.sView.pagingEnabled=YES;
self.sView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.sView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:self.sView];

self.sVC = [[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.sVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.sView.frame.size.width, self.sView.frame.size.height);

[self.sView addSubview:self.sVC.view];

[self addChildViewController:self.sVC];
}
```

**Sub ViewController**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.playView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
self.playView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

[self.view addSubview:self.playView];

UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(show:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[btn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[self.playView addSubview:btn];
}

- (void)show:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"--test");
}
```

Comment: just trying to understand, are you adding SubViewController's view as a subview to your MainViewController? Is SubViewController's class actually StartViewController?

Comment: Correct, my mainView is a scrollview and when I scroll down I'm seeing the subview with the button in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the main problem is that your button is outside its view controller view frame.

Your view controller is obviously (0, 0, 320, screenHeight) where screenHeight is either 568 or 480. This is the default behavior, you should probably never change it. 
**An event will be working only if it happens inside the view controller's frame.**

The problem with your code is that you have defined your playview frame as (0, screenHeight, 320, screenHeight). So this playview is below the viewcontroller's view where no event can be catched. Since your button is inside the playview it is not in the viewcontroller as well and it won't work.

What you should do is set your playview inside the view controller by setting its frame (0,0, 320, screenHeight) so that events will be catched. Then you can change the whole frame of your view controller when you add it to its parent.

In SubviewController :

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.playView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    self.playView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    [self.view addSubview:self.playView];

    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(show:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [btn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [self.playView addSubview:btn];
}

- (void)show:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"--test");
}
```

And in your MainView Controller :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.sView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    self.sView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.sView.frame.size.width,
                                self.sView.frame.size.height*2);
    self.sView.pagingEnabled=YES;
    self.sView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.sView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview:self.sView];

    self.sVC = [[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.sVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, _sView.frame.size.height, _sView.frame.size.width, _sView.frame.size.height);

    [self.sView addSubview:self.sVC.view];
    [self addChildViewController:self.sVC];
}
```

Comment: Well, that's working for me, have you changed the frame ? Is it crashing or just nothing happens ?

Comment: You'd have to give a little more details than just "it's not working" What is the view ? the scrollview ? Does not working means nothing happens?

Comment: It's how I did in the example. I'm creating a ScrollView (with paging) in my MainViewController. With a margin of one Screen I'm adding the SubViewController to the ScrollView (when you are paging vertical once). In that Subview is a Button, which I can see but not click on.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand what you have tried so far. Have you noticed the changes of frame ? The piece of code i wrote above, works perfectly fine for me (within a paged scrollview). I indeed had the same problem as you by copying your code, and the reason it wasn't working was because the UIButton was outside its viewcontroller frame.

Comment: I changed my code at the top. Is that how you meant? With this code my button is not working neither.

Comment: I have edited my code, try to just copy this instead of your method. I have just changed the frames. The playview needs to start at 0 on y origin and your sVC.view needs to start at your page height.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you! Now it works! And what exactly was the issue? Events are not working when a View has its origin not at 0?? 
That logic makes no sense for me...

Comment: Ahah i don't know if i'm not clear or if you didn't read carefully, but anyway i've updated my answer, hopefully so that you'll understand better.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable userinteraction of the parent scrollview

```
[_sView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: On the parent scrollview the interaction is working (i tested it). And enabling the interaction on the subViewController is not affecting the issue.